# Error while trying to debug flutter app on physical android phone

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when I try to debug my flutter application on my android physical device .

This is my debug console output :

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on SM A515F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-28).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\598e97d118bac3af7420b509a0bba7ba\transformed\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-28).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\39a13d14d6cfd824e114bd3c6574b2e2\transformed\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line of the output

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-28).
```

`minCompileSdk` must be lesser than `compileSdkVersion`. Correct it the `build.gradle` file (or inside the file showed in the error if the versions are right in the `build.gradle`) .

Comment: I got this is my gradle.build : 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_auth"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Then check the versions inside the file `aar-metadata.properties` in your error.